# Installed RBLDNSD for making a custom RBL but something is missing, could you help us?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, spam-filter, rbl

We have successfully installed RBLDNSD with the idea of having a custom RBL server.
Now we have started to make some testing adding some IPs to the our blacklist,
and also have configured Exim (Cpanel based) email server to read the information from the
RBL server, but it seems like it is not reading the information from my RBLDNSD server,
so now we need to find why? Could you help us with this?

In the following lines you can see some of the tests I have made:

```
root@s3 [~]# host 12.224.215.95.rbl.enlanube.pe rbl.enlanube.pe
Using domain server:
Name: rbl.enlanube.pe
Address: 162.243.209.40#53
Aliases:

12.224.215.95.rbl.enlanube.pe has address 127.0.0.2



root@s3 [~]# grep 95.215.224.12 /var/log/exim_mainlog
2014-04-17 08:22:18 1WalKb-0008ph-Vb <= prueba@roxfarmaperu.com H=enkompassmail1.ukdns.biz [95.215.224.12]:50997 P=esmtps X=TLSv1:AES128-SHA:128 S=2607 id=3826587a$616e23c8$38beaba4$@roxfarmaperu.com T="fw: Re: Prueba 6.49am" for prueba@avances.vo.pe
2014-04-17 08:22:18 SMTP connection from enkompassmail1.ukdns.biz [95.215.224.12]:50997 closed by QUIT
```

Comment: You wrote "have configured Exim...to read the information from the RBL server", but nothing in that log confirms that.  Add to your post the changes you made to your exim config, including which ACL(s) you put those changes in.  Note that order is important, so if you put an "accept" for all smtp auth users before this check, then RBL line will never get reached.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I followed the CPanel/WHM instructions:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ManageRbls

CPanel Forum thread:
http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/unified-list-blacklisted-smtp-ip-addresses-372181.html

Reference pictures:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0g032ucazssc99/Screenshot%202014-04-15%2014.05.19.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/etu3kevp1rhpj9p/Screenshot%202014-04-15%2014.05.37.png

Comment: They also suggested me to create a zone forwarder can be set up in /etc/named.conf however I have not done that because I guess that it makes no sense to make extra configuration on the email servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this is not an exim issue.  The problem is your DNS server configuration.  Look at your original submission in the Cpanel forum:

```
Mac-mini-de-Ale:~ ale$ host 214.124.58.198.rbl.enlanube.pe
Host 214.124.58.198.rbl.enlanube.pe not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Mac-mini-de-Ale:~ ale$ host 214.124.58.198.rbl.enlanube.pe rbl.enlanube.pe
Using domain server:
Name: rbl.enlanube.pe
Address: 162.243.209.40#53
Aliases:

214.124.58.198.rbl.enlanube.pe has address 127.0.0.2
```

If your DNS was configured properly, the first one would work.  Looking at your DNS, I see what the problem is:

```
rbl.enlanube.pe.    300 IN  NS  162.243.209.40.
```

The target of an NS record must be a hostname, not an IP address.  Step 1 is to remove that record.

DNS clients already know what DNS servers are responsible for answering queries to the enlanube.pe domain, and all subdomains.  You want to specifically set a different DNS server for the rbl.enlanube.pe domain and its subdomains.  So step 2 is to add the correct DNS records, so that resolver DNS clients know which server to ask for rbl.enlanube.pe and *.rbl.enlanube.pe.

```
rbl.enlanube.pe.    IN NS rbl.enlanube.pe.
```

You already have the A record for rbl.enlanube.pe, so adjusting the NS record by itself should fix the problem you are having.

Comment: Hello, I followed your tip but it seems to be not working as expected 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8ke7bfj1onaduq/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2013.25.08.png

Comment: Your dns is not fixed.  When I query your authoritative DNS (dns1/2.stabletransit.com) for rbl.enlanube.pe, it responds NXDomain instead of the nameserver above. Your public DNS is still preventing it from working right. Your image does show that whatever workstation you are using gets the correct info, but for the rest of us on the public internet, it's not working.

Comment: I got these additional instructions from the RBLDNSD mailing list
http://www.corpit.ru/pipermail/rbldnsd/2014q2/001231.html

What do you think?

Comment: He told you to do exactly what I told you to do and fix delegation for the "rbl.enlanube.pe" subdomain.  He just additionally recommended you to name your authoritative DNS something different than "rbl.enlanube.pe".  It ends up working the same either way (with one extra name lookup happening with his way): there is some DNS magic going on with each method.